# What to do if the CD I want to use cannot be run on ubuntu/linux

Tags: edubuntu, unsupported-packages, books

As a high-school, we decided to use Edubuntu on classes, labs etc. Edubuntu is OK with Activ Inspire. But we have a problem. We're from Turkey and we're learning English. So we use this book. But this book's CD is only for Windows and Mac. What to do? Help us :)

Cambridge Interchange 3
http://img1.imagesbn.com/p/9781107648708_p0_v1_s260x420.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the self-study MP3s from the [official Cambridge site](http://www.cambridge.org/interchange/audioprogram/?utm_source)...

I see now: you mean the Digibook:  Please [contact](http://www.cambridge.org/be/about-us/feedback) Cambridge and tell them what your problem is so they know that schools are also interested in Linux.

I the mean time, have your Computer Science teacher look into [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) which is a Windows Emulator running under Linux and Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot. We are a school. We just need the book. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I search for, you understood me. Yeah should contact with Cambridge. Also will try Wine.